# Answer my phone on my Tablet?

Tags: bluetooth, tablet, calls, voip

I have an Android phone (HTC Desire Z), I also have a Android tablet (Acer Iconia Tab A501).  I would like to link up my phone to my tablet so I can answer my phone on my tablet.

Is this possible with Bluetooth?
Is this possible with any apps?
Is this possible with Call-Fowarding to a VOIP?

Not sure if there is anything else to try.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your Google Voice number and receive calls at any computer.  The following snip comes from [Google's web site for Google Voice](http://googlevoiceblog.blogspot.co.uk/2010/08/make-and-receive-calls-in-gmail.html):

> Make and receive calls in Gmail Google Voice lets you manage all your
>   phone communications and seamlessly make and receive calls on any of
>   your existing phones. But what if you don’t have your phone with you?
>   Or what if you’re in a place with poor cell phone reception, or you’re
>   travelling internationally and don’t want to incur expensive roaming
>   charges? Wouldn’t it be great if you could use your computer to make
>   or receive calls?
>
> Starting today you can use Gmail to receive or place Google Voice
>   calls.
>
> To get started, check the box next to Google Chat in your list of
>   forwarding phones and the next time someone calls your Google Voice
>   number, Gmail will notify you of an incoming call. You can take the
>   call or even listen in as the caller leaves a message, in a single
>   step right from your computer

There you go, straight from the Google's mouth.

;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Google Voice to do that. You can set it up so that when someone calls your Voice number, both your phone and your tablet ring.

Comment: K, I will have to look in to this Google Voice thing, never used it.

Comment: Neither have I, but I've heard very good things about it.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make or receive a call directly through Google Voice. Even on a phone, it just forwards calls to you; it doesn't actually provide a VoIP service. You can probably set up GVoice to forward to something like Skype or GrooveIP, though.

Comment: Hm, you may be right... As I said, I've never used it.