# Answer phone calls directly from computer (Linux)

Tags: calls, remote-control

When I'm on my work computer, I'd like to connect my phone via USB and have the possibility to answer calls or initiate calls directly from my computer, using a microphone handset directly connected to the computer, not the phone.

I Googled assuming something like this already existed, but I didn't find that specific use (I found GtalkSMS, EasySMS, AirDroid, but most of them are for SMS/MMS only).

How can this be done?

It would be great if this would be directly connected to Google+ (like initiating a Hangout that would automatically use my phone, or a GTalk call that would use my connected phone instead of a "web" phone number).

Comment: Related: [Can I forward/reply calls/sms to PC?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/22247/16575), [Answer my phone on my Tablet?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/16575)

Comment: I read the two other links, but apparently, it does the opposite : receive call to Google Chat via a "Google Voice number". I want to receive call on my computer when someone dials my personal mobile number

Comment: Using bluetooth HFP it possible in Windows 7 PC's but don't know whether it will work in Linux. so if you have a windows pc you can try to connect you phone and try in advance phone operations window you can call using a PC

Comment: Related questions  [A](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9963/how-to-call-from-console), [B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14958845/how-to-make-a-call-from-linux-with-android-phone)

Answer (score 3):

The only Linux application I know that could achieve this is '[HFP for Linux](http://nohands.sourceforge.net/)'. It works by implementing the [Bluetooth HFP 1.5 Hands-Free Profile](http://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=41181&ei=fYYjUaTJD8GL4ASG-4FI&usg=AFQjCNFQr7WFavLbMqSiGaUsvOLbtj8vmg&sig2=zQvWe-UauOM_kbxaUCJa_g&bvm=bv.42553238,d.Yms) (PDF file), which basically makes your PC a remote control/headset for your Android phone.

Comment: this sounds cool. but how do i install this software?

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java application which you can use to connect your Android device with your Linux/Windows installation. It needs ADB.

As part of your question, without a USB, you can use ADB's `tcpip` function so you won't need a USB cable all the time. Just connect it once, enable `tcpip`, and then connect over a wireless connection.

It won't forward your incoming calls, but you can use your Android screen. I have written a [tutorial](https://abdullah.today/how-to-share-android-screen/) on its usage as well.
Once connected with ADB, you can dial a number from the phone like this:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.CALL -d tel:+12345678
```

Comment: this works but you can only call and then you have to go to your phone ....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've seen, there's no solution aside from ADB and custom coding to perform call forwarding over USB that can be trusted; Bluetooth self-induced MitM, I don't consider it very secure for client calls. Side note here, "Bad USB" (AKA Rubber Ducky or HID) attacks are too easy to deploy if your device is infected with the latest generation of cross-platform malware; if one cares about their workplace security, phones shouldn't be plugged into the corporate network or computers. So, I'll suggest what I know to have worked for providing similar features you've requested.

The trick I've used in the past doesn't require the phone to be connected to a PC to answer calls but should still work as desired; look up Google Voice number to forward calls to your cell or PC; an additional benefit of using Google Voice is that groups of contacts or individual contacts can have their own custom voice mail greetings setup.

Answer (score 0):

This is what one of Apple's "Continuity" features, "Handoff", does... yes? But Handoff's only good between Mac and iPhone, so I have used Google Voice to dial and answer calls to my Android phone on my Mac.

You can connect your phone to Google Voice or port your number to Google Voice and then you can use Hangouts to answer and make calls. (If you have Sprint, like I do, this works great! Just use your number as a Google Voice number and it's totally synced; unlike fully porting your number over, everything stays the same with your Sprint service except now you use Google Voice VM but it's better and more convenient anyhow and nothing changes from the phone-side).

Also, have you tried AirDroid (AirMirror)? I use AirDroid for controlling my phone from the computer (Mac App or Website > computer and phone must be hooked to the same network); I also have it set up as security and to find the location, in case my phone is lost or stolen. And I use Pushbullet's Chrome extension for texting [because it is easier and I discovered it first;)].

AirDroid(AirMirror) is almost like Handoff except I don't know if it accepts incoming calls, but you can make outgoing. Check out: http://gadgets.ndtv.com/apps/features/how-to-make-calls-send-and-receive-sms-from-your-computer-using-an-android-phone-654766

There are a couple company's that I read about that are said to offer this exact solution but I don't have personal experience (except
"Vysor", I have used as an Android mirroring app for presentations):

- Remote Phone call- https://www.justremotephone.com/
- *Mobizen- mobizen.com
- Vysor

*Seems like a great platform.

But ultimately, it seems like these are simply mirroring apps. Which actually could be just fine; the mirroring route is not as clean and fluid as Google Voice has been for me because of the necessary setup, every. single. time. But it could be an easy hack or workaround for this problem.  You just activate the mirroring system when you sit down for work on your computer, then plug your headset into your phone, and then you can use the app's screen mirroring your phone to answer or dial calls, etc.

Either way, there are so many apps and stuff out there, I'm sure there are other options but in my experience, Google Voice has been the best at doing what you asked, and it's simple and seamless > once you set it up, you can forget about it!

Comment: apple's "handoff" only works about 50% of the time. i have tried with iphone 6+ 6s+, and macbook pro's from 2012 all the way to 2016 - same story every time.  so that's a terrible comparison IMHO

Answer (score 0):

I use [Mightytext](https://mightytext.net/) as it allows you to dial phone calls and send SMS messages from the browser. I have used it on Windows & Linux with an android phone. No need for a USB connection either.