# How Link to Windows (Android application) call forwarding works when Google has added so many obstacles to call recording on Android?

Tags: applications, calls, windows, remote-control

Today, I bumped into Microsoft's [Link to Windows](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.microsoft.appmanager) Android application, which supports that it has a call forwarding feature so you can make and answer calls from a Windows computer. A few days ago I was wondering why KDE Connect doesn't have this feature and if I should try to implement it.

Then after a bit of searching, I found [this](https://www.pcmag.com/how-to/record-calls-on-your-android-phone) article describing the obstacles Google has added to call recording on Android. So reading that Link to Windows support call forwarding sounded somehow controversial to me.

The reason I am writing this question is to ask for more information about how it works and why this application is allowed on Google Play.

Comment: Possibly the call forwarding is using Bluetooth HFP 1.5 Hands-Free Profile (as mentioned in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/39912/44325)). I'm not sure what call recording has anything to do with this though...

Comment: @AndrewT. you are correct. The Play Store description of "Link to Windows" states: *“Calls requires a Windows 10 PC with Bluetooth capability”*.

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks you very much for the information. If you can write an answer about it I will accept it, otherwise I will answer it myself.

Comment: Feel free to answer it :)

Comment: @AndrewT. One more clarification, for the calling functionality to work the phone must be in the Bluetooth range not in the Wifi range, right?

Comment: Based on the Play Store description mentioned by Irfan, I believe so, because it's using Bluetooth technology.

Comment: Okay, thanks you for the infromation.