# How to answer phone calls in another phone via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, calls

I have two Android phones which I wanted to set up one as the one that answers calls for the second that could stay in the backpack. Is it possible to use a Android phone as a Bleutooth accesory, like a hands-free device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657784/call-transfer-from-one-device-to-another-through-bluetooth): you can't. ([It is possible for land lines though](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WKgV1NVhzo).)

Or you can forward your calls from one phone to the other, either by [changing the settings in your phone](http://www.techulator.com/resources/12042-How-to-setup-call-forward-and-redirect-in-Android-phones.aspx) or downloading [an app that does it all for you](http://www.phonearena.com/news/5-best-call-forwarding-apps-for-Android-smartphones_id70426).

The alternative solution that comes closest to what you're after is to install mysms mirror, which is an app that tells you when your other phone receives a call or text message, and lets you call back.  See [their blog](https://blog.mysms.com/quick-tip-mirror-your-calls-from-one-phone-to-another-phone.html).

Google Voice might also work for you. It's mentioned in the answer to this question: [Answer my phone on my Tablet?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/16883/answer-my-phone-on-my-tablet?rq=1)

Comment: HI @Monozygotic have you solved your issue.I am also looking for such type of work.

Comment: Hi @justchill, it was not my issue. I just supplied an answer. Please ask Gabriel Diego if it solved his issue.